# How to use getUpdates after setWebhook in Telegram Bot API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I use **setWebhook** for my telegram-bot and now I need to use **getUpdates**. I have read the docs, and they say, that I can use only one method.

The problem is, that I have in console:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Error: Conflict: another webhook is active"}
```

So the question is, how to **UNSET** webhook and use **getUpdates**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

as mentioned in Telegram bot api documentations you just need to pass empty string to `url` parameter.

```
> base_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + TOKEN + '/'
> data = {"url": ""}
> requests.post(base_url + 'setWebhook', data=data)
```

Answer (score 13):

In a browser send the following request:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot655390656:bhFS50...ff3zO4/setwebhook
```

Comment: most useful answer

Answer (score 0):

you can just call the method

```
deleteWebhook()
```

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletewebhook

for example using telepot

```
import telepot
bot = telepot.Bot('YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN')
bot.deleteWebhook()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small rake task for this job

```
require 'net/https'

namespace :telegram_custom do
  desc "Deactives webhook - this is needed to enable polling in development"
  task deactivate_webhook: :environment do
    token = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"
    base_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot#{token}/setwebhook"
    uri = URI.parse(base_url)

    res = Net::HTTP.get URI(base_url)
    puts res
  end
end
```

If you have the token stored in the credentials you can get them via: `token = Rails.application.credentials.telegram[:bot]`